# Request entity too Large while uploading image files using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '/uploadedProfilePics')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname)
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Error while uploading image files to express server using multer

```
>  PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    >     at readStream (/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    >     at getRawBody (/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    >     at read (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    >     at urlencodedParser (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:116:5)
    >     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    >     at trim_prefix (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    >     at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    >     at Function.process_params (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    >     at next (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    >     at jsonParser (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:119:7)
    > message: 'request entity too large',   expected: 299371,   length:
    > 299371,   limit: 102400,   type: 'entity.too.large'
```

I reviewed all my code and it is only necessary that amount of evidence to show what I want more than that will reveal much of my project.

how to handle this error.

Comment: What is the size of file you are trying to upload?

Comment: Check limits option from following link - https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try, allowing the limit ar body parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'5mb'})); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit:'5mb'}));
```